# Socket fix error TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, sockets

I have to 
 Connect to alien server ('localhost', 10000),
Then send USER followed by aliensignal

But I get an error message that's mean that the format of my .send is incorrecte.
Do you know what's the good way to send two differents string in one .send?

```py
import socket
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect (('localhost', 10000))
clientsocket.send('USER:','aliensignal') 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/usercode.py", line 15, in <module>
clientsocket.send('USER:','aliensignal')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: The signature of the send function is as follows, where the last parameter passed to send function is an integer. You are passing 'aliensignal', which is a string  as the last parameter 

def send(self, data, flags=0)

Answer (score 0):

[[Python 3.Docs]: socket.**send**(*bytes[, flags]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send)'s (optional) *flags* argument must be an integer (normally you shouldn't use it, but if you want more details check [[man7]: RECV(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html)).

As for your current case, you can either:

- Call *send* twice (once for each of them):

  ```py
  clientsocket.send(b"USER:")
  clientsocket.send(b"aliensignal")
  ```
- Concatenate the strings (*bytes*) and send them both at once:

  ```py
  clientsocket.send(b"USER:aliensignal")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [socket.send()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) say the second positional argument(s) are `int`, not `str`.  It further states more information about this argument can be found in recv(2) of a Unix manual.  Here, at least, is a Linux man page for [recv(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recv)

Answer (score 0):

`send` only takes a string and option integer flags that normally aren't used.  TCP is just a byte stream and there are no message boundaries.  The protocol for what makes a complete message must be defined.  Your alien server needs to be a bit more specific.

You can do:

```
clientsocket.send(b'USER:aliensignal')
```

but you can also do variations of the following.  The bytes are just entered into the transmit buffer in the same order.

```
clientsocket.send(b'USE')
clientsocket.send(b'R:a')
clientsocket.send(b'liens')
clientsocket.send(b'ignal')
```

So how does alien server know you've sent a complete message?  Here are some possible ways:

- Close the client connection.  The server can keep reading bytes until it `recv` returns 0, which means the client closed the connection.
- Use a delimiter.  Send a newline `\n` character at the end of the message.  The server can read until it finds a newline and know that it has the complete message.  If it reads beyond the newline, it can save the excess as part of the next incoming message.
- Send the length in bytes of the message, then the message.  `send(b'\x16User:aliensignal')` for example.  For longer messages, the protocol can agree on the length and endianness of the message, e.g. 32-bit (4-byte) big-endian length.